# Why isn't my jQuery function passing the parameter and changing it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set a function with parameter color. I am then trying to get the input text thats typed in and to change colour of the div according to the text input by passing through the parameter.

My current attempts are not working, any help or ideas please?

**html snippet**

```
    <div class="bulb" id="bulb1"></div>
    <button id="setColor">Color set</button>
    <input type="text" id="colorText"></input>
```

**jquery**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


    $('#setColor').click(function()
    {
        $( "#colorText" ).is( color );

        setColor(color);

        $('#colorText').val('');

    });


});

function setColor(color){

    $('#bulb1').css({'background-color': color});   

}
```

Comment: `$( "#colorText" ).is( color );` What do you expect that to do? `color` is undefined within that click handler...

Comment: You are attempting to use a variable `color` that does not exist. Also what do you expect the line `$( "#colorText" ).is( color );` to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


  $('#setColor').click(function()
  {
    var color = $( "#colorText" ).val();  // Get the color in the input box.

    setColor(color);

    $('#colorText').val('');

  });


});

function setColor(color){

   $('#bulb1').css({'background-color': color});   

}
```

Here you go : http://jsfiddle.net/mwjfz7tq/

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I've added some height and width to your div so it is visible):

```
<div class="bulb" style="height:50px; width:50px" id="bulb1"></div>
<button id="setColor">Color set</button>
<input type="text" id="colorText"></input>
```

And here is the JS(I have changed it to capture the text and pass it to the setColor function.):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#setColor').click(function()
    {
        var c = $( '#colorText' ).val();
        setColor(c);

        $('#colorText').val('');
    });
});

function setColor(color){
    $('#bulb1').css({'background-color': color});
}
```